# Browse MahApps resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, catalog, dynamicresource

I started with MahApps and would like to know how to browse MahApps resources in general similar to Object catalog in Visual Studio. Like I am able to read all available Icons in the the icons.xaml in resource folder, I would like to be able to do so, for any DynamicResource such as AccentColorBrush.

If this is not possible, how am I supposed to know about my possibilities and the capabilities of MahApps since XAML does not know suggestions?

Comment: Download mah apps metro from GitHub there's a sample project in it.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I downloaded the sample project. It is the same as just following the quick start guide. I just would like to open the xaml-files which are references in app.xaml. E.g. Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}" Where can I actually find the definition to MaterialDesignPaper or at least, which other options are available?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html

Under the **Creating Custom Accents and Themes** chapter (about the end of the page), you can see all possible **x:Key** of colors and brushes according with the selected theme in **App.xaml** resources.